# How to profile an app that uses IPC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have implemented part of activity monitor using NSTAsk and NSPipe.
This is very slow. Is there any other method to implement it ?

And also tell me how to get samples of prcesses.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see where most of the time is being spent ?

Comment: when top command is executed using NSTask was taking more time.

Comment: I Used multi-threads, it is much better than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have implemented part of activity monitor using NSTAsk and NSPipe. This is very slow.

I rather doubt it.

Maybe your app or your helper tool is slow, but that's what Instruments is for.

> Is there any other method to implement it ?

Yes. Look up “IPC” in the Xcode documentation viewer; there are many ways for two processes to communicate.

> And also tell me how to get samples of prcesses.

The best way for a developer is Instruments's Time Profiler instrument. The other way, and the best for users (handy when they report a hang), is Activity Monitor's Sample Process button.

Comment: How to get samples of Processes with coding.